# How to run scheduled tasks one at a time, not simultaneously

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

The task scheduler in my Windows 10 has a number of scheduled tasks created by applications. Every single application considers it its duty to create at least a task to run an updater. One day, it looks like all the tasks start at once, and I have to wait quite a long time for the computer resources to be released.

I tried to remove some tasks from the scheduler, but applications create them again. Moreover, I don't like an idea that I have to search and remove a tasks for every installed application. But I would like to regularize tasks run somehow.

Is it true that on Windows 10 a number of scheduled tasks may run simultaneously? If yes, how can I set up the scheduler to run scheduled tasks one at a time?

EDIT: The point is most of tasks has "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" enabled. For example, if my computer returns from hibernation, do all the missed tasks run at once or not? If yes, I'd like to set up the scheduler to run scheduled tasks one at a time. Of course, I can change setting for each task in the list, but I don't want to set up every new task manually, and check all the time if an application restores a task settings back.

Comment: I have a multitude of apps here and most of them do not use Task Scheduler to update. I do not get any kind of collision of schedules.

Answer (score 0):

> One day, it looks like all the tasks start at once

Does it reproduce that all tasks run at the same time?

Generally, we can check the schedules in task scheduler, you may check and set the tasks in task scheduler:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Does it reproduce that all tasks run at the same time?" This is what I'm asking. The point is most of tasks has "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" enabled. For example, if my computer returns from hibernation, do all the missed tasks run at once or not? If yes, I'd like to set up the scheduler to run scheduled tasks one at a time. Of course, I can change setting for each task in the list, but  I don't want to set up every new task manually, and check all the time if an application restores a task settings back.